# How to write a simple chat, without a database on meteor.js and react.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, meteor, websocket

I want to write a simple chat on `meteor.js` and thus I do not want to store the data in the `database`.
But I never found how to make an application without a `database`.

Here is an example of code as I can imagine.
Server code:

```
export let ws = [{_id:'1', text:'test1'}, {_id:'2', text:'test2'}];
Meteor.publish('ws', function wsPub() { return ws; });
let ctr = 3;
Meteor.methods({
    'addMsg'(text) {  ws.push({_id:ctr+1, text:text});  }
});
```

and client code:

```
import {ws} from '../api/model.js';

class Rtc extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  addMsg(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    Meteor.call('addMsg', this.refs.input.value);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         {this.props.ws.map((item, i)=>{ 
           return(<span key={i._id}>{item.text}</span>); 
         })}
         <input type="text" ref="input" />
         <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick={this.addMsg.bind(this)}/>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
export default createContainer( () => {
  Meteor.subscribe('ws');
  return { ws: ws };
}, Rtc);
```

but I do not understand what I wrote is not so in the `createContainer`?

UPD: I updated server code, but still websockets does not work:

```
Meteor.publish('ws', function wsPub() {
  let self = this;
  ws.forEach( (msg)=> {
    self.added( "msg", msg._id, msg.text );
  });
  self.ready();
  // return ws;
});
```

Comment: Just wondering, if you don't want Meteor's pub/sub system's strengths, why use Meteor?

Comment: @MasterAM I like the system of pub/sub but not always tedious that it stored in the database, and not always in mongodb. There are very different cases and tasks. Here we assume right now without it took to make a base vebrts and I'm trying to understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control what is sent over a publish, get a reference to the "publish instance" (really a specific client with a specific subscription) and use its `add`/`change`/`remove` commands:

```
let messages = [];
let clients = [];
Meteor.publish('ws', function() {
    clients.push(this);
    _.each(messages, (message) => {this.added('msg', message._id, message);});
    this.ready();
});
Meteor.methods({
    addMsg(text) {
        let newMessage = {_id: Meteor.uuid(), text: text};
        messages.push(newMessage);
        _.each(clients, (client) => {client.added('msg', newMessage._id, newMessage);});
    }
});
```

Regarding your code that you wrote in an update: you're sending a `string` where the function `added` expects a document (an `object`). Also, unlike this example above, you do not tell the clients when the `ws` (messages array) has changed.

I'd recommend also renaming these things to be more verbose and clear :)

Comment: well, I replaced the server-side code, but unfortunately the application did not work reactively. Maybe I'm doing something wrong in the client version?

Comment: What I added here is how to get it to work reactively. You neglected to actually notify the clients when the messages array changed. The right place to do that is in the body of the method.

Comment: when I send a message to the client, it is not displayed simultaneously on other clients.
And I don't know what else to do to get it working. Because server-side code like normal then I assumed something is wrong with the client code.

Comment: The code as you've written it will never work, because `self.added( "msg", msg._id, msg.text )` will never work—you can't send a string where `added` expects a document/object (in the third parameter). Supposing you fixed this, you would need to do what I have done above and call `added` on each subscribed client whenever a message is sent.

Comment: I have done what is written in this answer. But still if one client adds a chat message that other clients don't see this message.
Аnd I assumed that I wrote something in createContainer in client code.

Comment: I realized why not work because the client code should have taken the data from minimongo.

Answer (score 1):

What you suppose won't work. Because `Meteor.publish` returns a cursor to a `Collection` or `array` of `Collections`. According to the [official documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html):

> Publish functions can return a Collection.Cursor, in which case Meteor will publish that cursor’s documents to each subscribed client. You can also return an array of Collection.Cursors, in which case Meteor will publish all of the cursors.

Again, when you subscribe to a publication, it stores the data(as cursor to the same collection as the publication) locally in [MiniMongo](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#mongo_collection). So a chat without database is not technically possible with pub-sub in Meteor.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the code, and made to return the server part of an array of collections. But I still do not see the reactivity, and chat is not updated after sending messages :(

Comment: This is not entirely accurate, as returning a cursor is only one of the ways of publishing data. You can manually send `added` messages (and others) and perhaps even use a local (in-memory) collection server-side (I think that I used one in one of my extensions for publications).

Comment: @MasterAM You can answer or reference give a simple example in this context?